# Como faço para fazer uma interação entre duas tabelas (<table>) com AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Preciso fazer uma interação entre duas tabelas em uma aba lateral, onde inicialmente uma tabela "resposta" fica escondida e a tabela "pergunta" estará disponível e assim que no `input` de pesquisa acima delas eu digitar algo via AJAX automaticamente aparecerá na tabela "pergunta", até ai resolvi

Como esconder a segunda tabela que é a que eu quero que apareço somente após eu clicar em um item? Ou seja, a pergunta da primeira tabela e a primeira tabela suma neste momento.

Comment: Se a questão é SOMENTE de "sumir" e "aparecer", você pode usar `$('#tabela_para_sumir').css('display', 'none');` e `$('#tabela_para_aparecer').css('display', 'block');`, acrescente no elemento de `id="tabela_para_aparecer"` o parâmetro `style="display:none;"`. Se você não estiver usando JQuery, utilize funções similares, com a finalidade de alterar o `display` do CSS. Você também pode obter por usar `$(...).hide()` e `$(...).show()`, para as respectivas funções, caso use JQuery.

Comment: Você só precisa utilizar ajax caso vá fazer alguma requisição no banco. Na questão você não menciona isso. Se não for fazer nenhuma requisição pode tentar o que o amigo acima sugeriu.

Comment: Então Inkeliz e Joao Paulo, obrigado pelas explicações , me ajudaram a clarear a mente, pois bem eu utilizei no document.ready o $("#teste_faq_resposta").hide(); e logo quando acesso a pagina esta escondida beleza mas ai na tabela onde eu consigo captar os dados do BD que preciso que são as perguntas da tabela no mysql chamada "nomeconfidencial"_faq ao clicar em uma linha onde esta a pergunta a qual eu preciso que apareça a resposta posteriormente não consigo fazer aparecer a outra tabela ou seila qual tipod e tag usar ja tentei usar "p" para aparecer a resposta e esconder a pergunta.

Comment: pessoal valeu pelas dicas consegui fazer desaparecer e aparecer outra tabela com as respostas agora meu próximo passo é fazer aparecer exatamente a resposta da pergunta a qual selecionei, alguem tem alguma dica? agradeço de coração!

Answer (score 1):

Para saberes qual foi a linha que selecionaste poderás fazer o seguinte, no html:

```
    <table id="table">
 <tr id="1">
  <td>A</td>      
  <td>B</td>      
 </tr>
 <tr id="2">
  <td>C</td>      
  <td>D</td>      
  </tr>    
</table>
```

e em jquery para obteres essa mesma linha poderás fazer o seguinte

```
$('tr[id=' + id + ']').remove(); 
// id será o valor que queres passar no caso é 2 , neste caso vai apagar a linha
```

exemplo em uma função:

```
function qualLinha(){
$('#table tr').click(function (event) {
      alert($(this).attr('id')); //alerta qual foi o id da linha que selecionaste
 });
}
```